# Check if file exists when unknown extension

Tags: php, iterator, filesystems

I know the directory and filename but not the file's extension. What is the best way to determine if `/somedir/file.jpg` exists if all I have to go on is `/somedir/file`? My current method would be using a directory iterator to get the filenames of all the files in the directory without the extension and breaking on the first match e.g. if `file === file`.

Comment: How do you reference it when serving? Why is the extension missing?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php

Comment: Its part of an upload script, I store the originals in a separate folder where the filename is the same as the uploaded file but the extension may differ from `.jpg` (the one I am converting to with resizing). When I delete a particular file I want to delete the original as well (thus I know the path and the filename) - yes I know I could store it in the database.

Comment: @JazZ "For now, this function is not available on non-POSIX compliant systems except Windows."

Comment: Your system is non-POSIX ?

Comment: Sorry read it wrong (tired) :)

Comment: No problem. ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator` to filter out only matching basename minus the extension:

```
<?php
$file = './somedir/file';

$filter = new \RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator(
    new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator(dirname($file), \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), 
    function ($current, $key, $iterator) use ($file) {
        return !$current->isDir() && $current->getBasename('.'.$current->getExtension()) == basename($file);
    }
);
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter);
```

Then on that you can, check found:

```
if (iterator_count($iterator) > 0) {
    //found
} else {
    //not found
}
```

or, get values:

```
// get the first filepath
$filename = $iterator->getPathname();

// or loop it if your expecting multiple extensions
foreach($iterator as $file) {
   echo $file->getPathname().PHP_EOL;
}
```

And it that fails, you could always use `glob()`

```
if (!empty(glob($file.".*"))) { 
    echo 'File found'; 
}
```

Comment: Weirdly if I give it: `projects/140099329/originals/140099329_3`, I get the first file in the directory `projects/140099329/originals/140099329_1.png` ... The originals for the other uploaded files for a given item are also in that folder (a point I didn't think relevant till now). If it were the only file in the `/originals` directory I would have just removed that directory entirely.

Comment: I cant see how its matching `140099329_3` to `140099329_1.png`, might need to see a tree of the directory structure so can test it.

Comment: I'm feeding it this as `$file`: C:\xampp\htdocs\images\uploads\projects/140099329/originals/140099329_3

Comment: Is `140099329_3` a filename? so `140099329_3.png` is in `originals` folder?

Comment: Yup! here is a dir tree: https://imgur.com/a/3mOe3. Weird bc basename and dirname are all evaluating as expected.

Comment: I cant reproduce the wrong result, i've just setup and passed `$file = './uploads/projects/140099329/originals/140099329_2';` and it finds only `./uploads/projects/140099329/originals/140099329_2.png`  which is expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164453/discussion-between-alex-and-lawrence-cherone).